# sql select polish characters

Tags: sql, xpages-ssjs, utf, db2-400

I have a `db2` database with Polish text stored as `ccsid870`.

I would like to read it with an sql select and then `rs.getString("fieldname")`
The text I'm getting back doesn't show Polish diacritic characters (Ą, Ś, ś, ć etc…) correctly.

The url I'm using is `url:string="jdbc:odbc:DB2";IANAAppCodePage='2044'"` (kind of java on an ibm domino server)

Maybe the problem is this `IANAAppCodePage`. What should it be?

Or maybe it's the `odbc.ini` which contains `CharactersetFor65535=20228` and also `IANAAppCodePage=4`What should that be ?

Comment: There's an extra " (after DB2) in the url variable. Is that on purpose? If so, then you should encode it so that it doesn't close your string variable.

Comment: Sorry , it's a typing misstake

Comment: If you are using JDBC, can you try the jtopen driver -- https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/.